# Can I get another app's NSApplication?

Tags: cocoa, objective-c

I'm trying to write a simple native executable that can be run by developers in the terminal, and all the executable does is make the terminal dock icon "bounce" for attention.

So if you had some very long running process, you could write this:

```
$ sleep 100; bounce
```

where bounce is the executable, and after the process is done you will get alerted by the bounce.

So far, I've found that I want to call `requestUserAttention` on the Terminal's `NSApplication`.  And I've managed to get the Terminal's `NSRunningApplication` by calling `runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Terminal"`.

However, I can't call `requestUserAttention` from the `NSRunningApplication`.  It must be called from `NSApplication`.

Is there any way to access the Terminal's `NSApplication`, so I can call this method, or are those exclusively private to app that owns it?

Comment: AppleScript is probably your best bet. MacOS doesn't tend to like processes poking at each other indiscriminately. Thats not saying some heavy duty Objective-C runtime hacking might not work https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective_c_runtime?changes=_5

Comment: See [How to make Terminal bounce its application Dock icon in OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/246353/how-to-make-terminal-bounce-its-application-dock-icon-in-os-x).